# Google Sheets script to paste Range above for n times

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have an issue that I couldn't figure out.
I want to copy range A5:G10 with the format and paste above n times.
I will put frequency in cell D2. So the script will copy the range and paste above n time(n=Number in cell D2).

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xCzkTG_hsV51pIEmcRvuHUmf1rebGw-CqcaGzFDzN7o/edit#gid=0)

I wanted to paste the range n times above, I have a little knowledge of Google Sheet Script, so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet directly into the question body including showing what you have tried and make it clear what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function! I've tested it in your sheet and created a personalized menu called "Copy". Feel free to modify the values to get them as spaced as you may need:

```
function copyNtimes() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
 var range = sheet.getRange("A5:G10") 
 var times = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()
 sheet.insertRowsAfter(11,7*times)
 SpreadsheetApp.flush()
 for (i=0;i<times;i++){
   range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(12+7*i,1,6,6)) //you can change that 12 or 7 to determine how much spaced you want the new tables
 }
}
//if you want to create a menu to do it, also use this function:
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Copy")
    .addItem("Copy n times","copyNtimes")
    .addToUi()

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is working fine, just one issue why is it deleting old data that is below? I want to keep that below as it is.

Comment: Because you haven't stated you had more information below  You need to insert new rows after this chart and before the other information, or copy the new charts at the end of the sheet (after the other information)?

Comment: Oh my bad, I haven't stated that. Is it possible we can change this script a little bit and it paste above the existing range? I think it is pasting below now.

Comment: Try new version!